# Search a string between two timestamps starting from bottom of file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I was trying to find a string `Cannot proceed: the cube has no data` in huge test.txt file only between timestamps yesterday 22:30 pm to today 00:30 am.

**Script:**

```
tac test.txt | awk -v today=$(date "+%d") -v yesterday=$(date "+%d" -d yesterday) '/Cannot proceed: the cube has no data/ {f=$0; next} f{if (($3==yesterday && $4>"22:30:00") || ($4==today && $4<="00:30:00")) {print; print f} f=""}'
```

**test.txt:**

```
[Thu Jun  8 07:56:17 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1019022)
Writing Database Mapping For [data]

[Thu Jun  8 12:56:38 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1250008)
Setting Outline Paging Cachesize To [8192KB]

[Thu Jun  8 22:56:20 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013202)
Cannot proceed: the cube has no data 

[Thu Jun  8 23:26:18 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013205)
Received Command [Load Database]

[Thu Jun  9 00:16:23 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1019018)
Writing Parameters For Database 

[Thu Jun  9 00:21:20 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013205)
Writing Parameters For Database 

[Thu Jun  9 00:29:00 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013205)
Cannot proceed: the cube has no data

[Thu Jun  9 01:25:21 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1019018)
Cannot proceed: the cube has no data
```

**output:**

```
[Thu Jun  8 22:56:20 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013202)
Cannot proceed: the cube has no data
```

Why not all strings matching the requiremnts are coming in output ? what I'm missing here ?

Comment: Typo. You want `$3 == today` instead of `$4 == today`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas...corrected and tested with new dates but still only one entry is coming in output..modified one: `tac test.txt | awk -v today=$(date "+%d") -v yesterday=$(date "+%d" -d yesterday) '/Cannot proceed: the cube has no data/ {f=$0; next} f{if (($3==today && $4<="00:30:00") || ($4==yesterday && $4>="22:30:00")) {print; print f} f=""}'`

Comment: You still have `$4==yesterday` above.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas..But if I'll not bind that then how I can get string ONLY `between timestamps yesterday 22:30 pm to today 00:30 am` ??..please elaborate.

Comment: The day is in field 3 not 4. `$4==yesterday && $4>="22:30:00"` does not make sense, you can't have `$4` being at the same time yesterday's day and being a _time_ greater than `"22:..."`. `$3==yesterday && $4>="22:30:00"`

Comment: Because of `tac` messages appear before dates. That's whay you are missing the event at 00:29. By the time you realize it's 00:29 you already missed the message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `awk` and so can't offer specific advice on its operations, but I'm fairly sure this would work:

```
tac ./file |
sed -e "/$(date -d"2 days ago")/q" -e \
    '/Cannot proceed: the cube has no data/!d;h;n;G'
```

If you read in a file backwards with `tac` as you do then your target error should appear first, with the dateline following it. So it `h`olds the last line after encountering target, pulls in the next and appends that last to the end - effectively reordering them.

It `d`eletes all other lines.

It continues this search until it encounters a 2-day old date at which time it just `q`uits.